# Custom class for previous and next functionality

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a PHP page with First Name and Last Name, Address, ZIP and other fields. I would like to have 'Add More' button, 'Previous' button and 'Save' button. When 'Add More' button clicked I would like to set the posted field values in custom class and save in session not to the database. The 'Previous' button should retrieve the field values from the custom class and display on the page. The 'Save' button should push everything at one time to the database. Are there any examples to achieve this kind of functionality? What is better way of getting this done? I am new to PHP. Please let me know if there any suggestions. Thank you. I appreciate any input.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is highly generic, if you are new to PHP you should look at some simple examples of how this is done by others... There are tons of online tutorials that will take you through similar problems + solutions. ... I just googled 'simple php address book examples' and found a number of places for instance [Simple PHP web based address book using MySQL](http://alpho011.hubpages.com/hub/Simple-PHP-web-based-address-book-using-MySql). Give it a go... Once you have specific problems you can easily post your questions here again. :-) Best of luck.

Comment: I have already went through lot of examples. But I couldn't any example on this specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

couldst try to use this

```
$ updateGoTo = "pagephp";
   if (isset ($ _SERVER ['QUERY_STRING'])) {
     $ updateGoTo .= (strpos ($ updateGoTo,'?'))? "&": "";
     $ updateGoTo .= $ _SERVER ['QUERY_STRING'];
   }
   header (sprintf ("Location: page.php", $ updateGoTo));
}
```